# iOS AVQueuePlayer flickering when playing videos with different aspect ratios

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avqueueplayer

I am using `AVQueuePlayer` to play several videos in a sequence. Everything works fine until there are videos with different aspect ratio. When the next `AVPlayerItem` starts -  the previous item stretches too early and one can see an ugly distortion for a second. Is this an iOS bug or do I need to do some handling in codes?

An example of such behavior is recorded [**HERE**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By3C8Xa2Re6TNmlUQ0lrMHlVdFk/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: post your code, make its easier to know what exactly happened.